# "Carefully considering" vs. "carefully consider"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I have a sentence like:

> We recommend carefully consider these variations ..

Is the sentence grammatically correct? Or is using *considering* instead of *consider* better?

Comment: You can leave it as *consider* if you insert *you* before *carefully*: *We recommend* ***you*** *carefully consider these variations.* In fact, if you insert the *you*, it should be *consider*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Recommend" is followed by an -ing verb to suggest that something would be suitable for a particular purpose. Hence, you should use **considering**.